# mod_rewrite map doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I am trying to build a simple mod_rewrite map to have category names translated into ids like so: ../category/electronics -> category.php?cat=1

The map is placed inside the www folder. The code ignores the map as if it doesn't exist

This is my rewrite code, what is wrong?

edited: path to catmap.txt, now it's working correctly

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "${path}/www"
....
RewriteMap cat2id txt:${path}/www/catmap.txt
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteRule ^/beta/category/(.*) /beta/category.php?cat={cat2id:$1}
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RewriteRule should be:

`RewriteRule ^/beta/category/(.*) /beta/category.php?cat=${cat2id:$1}`

I created the file `/var/www/beta/category.php` with the following contents:

`<?php print_r($_GET); ?>`

And this is what I get:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost/beta/category/electronics'
Array
(
    [cat] => 1
)
```

Comment: Yes, works.. thank you. 
But I am having trouble placing the map file inside the www folder
I need it there so I can auto generate the map file with php. Or that's a bad idea?

Comment: why not pass 'electronics' directly to the PHP and do the rest in your code? Anyway, you can change the path using `txt:/var/www/catmap.txt` on the rewritemap.

Comment: I am just testing with the categories, I have over 10,000 products. I really don't know what is the best, I am still trying different ways. Please do advise

Comment: If you are in doubt about what is best in this case, I would advise to post on stackoverflow.com instead, as it will get the right attention.